# Constants and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Can constants in CodeIgniter be used for things like recurring text (say metatags and meta-descriptions) throughout the site?  Something like:

```
define('METADESCRIPTION', 'This is my site');
```

and then echo METADESCRIPTION into the meta tags?

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo METADESCRIPTION; ?>">
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.

For access throughout the app you can define constants in config.php or even in index.php files.

config.php or in index.php

```
define('METADESCRIPTION', 'This is my site');
```

on your controllers or views.

assing

```
$myVar = METADESCRIPTION;
```

or access

```
echo METADESCRIPTION;
```

Comment: -1 This link is not working anymore that is why it is good to provide some explanation and not just a link.

Comment: @anujYadav thanks for checking this out. i've added explanations and removed the dead link. Sadly Ellislab moved the ci forum and broke the old links..

Comment: constants should be defined in config/constants.php i guess. !!! Not config.php or in index.php